# Sigbart When Trying To Get Library Image Picker

Tags: swift, xcode

When I try to get the image picker controller for my social media app, it gives me an error!

```
[access] <private>
```

I tried making another project and using other view controllers and UITapGestureRecognizers but nothing works!
Please help!

Console:
2016-07-21 17:43:29.439339 Post[3012:763270] [Accessibility] ****************** Loading GAX Client Bundle ****************
2016-07-21 17:43:31.098400 Post[3012:763270] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-07-21 17:43:31.108233 Post[3012:763270] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2016-07-21 17:43:37.273218 Post[3012:763430] [access] 
(lldb)

Code:

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,    UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
@IBAction func test(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let pickerImg = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerImg.delegate = self
    pickerImg.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    pickerImg.allowsEditing = true
    present(pickerImg, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in future versions of Swift.